# Java Getting 10 Boolean values and randomizing them

Tags: java, boolean

This is my first post so sorry if I'm doing something wrong!

I am trying to make a program where you enter a width and a height. From these 2 values, it takes 10 of them and randomly sets those 10 values to true or false. Just a side note, this is a school assignment that I've been having trouble with.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is the question that I was given:

> Task 1:
>
> 1. Create new class "BinaryMap"
> 2. Create new Method "generateRandomArrayFix" which creates a 2D boolean array sized 10x10
> 3. Initialize all values with false
> 4. 10 out of the 100 values should be randomly changed to true
> 5. return your boolean array.

```
import java.util.Random;
import Prog1Tools.IOTools;

public class BinaryMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[][] array = generateRandomArray();
    //  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //     printArray(array[i]);
    // }
    }

    private static void printArray(boolean[] booleans) {
    }

    /**
     * Ändert einen Wert im gegebenen daten-Array;
     * aus wahr wird falsch und aus falsch wird wahr
     *
     * @param daten - Array welches verändert werden soll
     * @param x     - x-Koordinate des Wertes
     * @param y     - y-Koordinate des Wertes
     */
    static void updateArray(boolean[][] daten, int x, int y) {
    }

    private static boolean[][] generateRandomArrayFix() {
        // Random rand = new Random();
        /*
         * 10 random aus 100
         */
        boolean[][] randomArray;
        int x = 10, y = 10;
        randomArray = new boolean[x][y];
        for (x = 0; x < randomArray.length; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < randomArray.length; y++) {
                randomArray[x][y] = false;
            }
        }
        return randomArray;
    }

    private static boolean[][] generateRandomArray() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rowWidth = IOTools.readInt("Enter Grid Width: ");
        int colHeight = IOTools.readInt("Enter Grid Height: ");
        boolean[][] board = new boolean[rowWidth][colHeight];
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx) {
            //fill the grid
            for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                    board[row][col] = rand.nextBoolean();
                }
            }
            //display output
            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
                    //System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            return board;
        }
        return board;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've posted requirements and unexplained code, but have asked no specific question  yet. Please read the [help] and the [ask] to see how to improve this question.

Comment: Which part of *"10 out of the 100 values should be randomly changed to true"* is troubling you? You randomly generate a coordinate (x,y) into the 10x10 matrix. If the value there is already `true`, generate a new random coordinate. Set value to `true`. Repeat 10 times.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a way to generate a coordinate

Comment: `int x = rand.nextInt(10); int y = rand.nextInt(10);`

Comment: erm still having a bit of trouble. Not too sure how to implement this into my current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Unfortunately the code you've posted has quite a few problems (including syntax errors) so it's quite difficult for us to suggest specific changes to solve your problem.

Rather than providing a solution to the requirements I suggest you start by breaking down the task into several steps and turn each into a method that you validate (through unit tests) before moving on to the next one.

So, for example, the first task is: create a 10x10 array initiated to false. Writing a test for this might be the only tricky part. Something like:

```
class BinaryMap {
    public int countValues(boolean value) {
        ...
    }
}

class BinaryMapTest {
    @Test
    void testInitialisation() {
        BinaryMap map = new BinaryMap():
        assertThat(map.countValues(false)).isEqualTo(100);
        assertThat(map.countValues(true)).isEqualTo(0);
    }
}
```

I suggest you get that code working before moving on to the random assignment of `true` values.

In this case, really the only tricky thing to avoid is just generating 10 random positions and assigning them to `true`. If you happen to generate duplicates you'll have less than 10 `true` values in the array.

So instead of:

```
for 10 iterations
    assign random value to true
```

You need

```
while there are less than 10 true values
    assign random value to true
```